# Remove top/left/right margins without using position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a div that will take 100% width of the very top of the screen, I can't seem to remove the margins without using `position:absolute`. is there any way of doing it?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have an example page or CSS that you're using? Did you try `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
html, body
{
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
```

Even better, apply a reset CSS to normalize other styles. Here's [one example](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Works! I did the same for the div, but should have tried to do the same for the body.. thanks!